# Boto generate_url for S3 PUT doesn't work with IAM roles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-iam

I use the following Python/Boto code to generate one-time file-upload URLs to an Amazon S3 bucket:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

def get_signed_upload_url():
    s3 = S3Connection(ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, is_secure=True)
    return s3.generate_url(300, 'PUT', bucket=BUCKET, key=KEY,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
```

It has worked fine for several years, and it continues to work today.

But now, I'm in the process of converting to IAM roles — which will save me from hard-coding the `ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. Hence, I have removed the hard-coded keys, resulting in this code:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

def get_signed_upload_url():
    s3 = S3Connection(is_secure=True)
    return s3.generate_url(300, 'PUT', bucket=BUCKET, key=KEY,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
```

With *this* code, whenever I generate a URL and do a `PUT` request to it from my client-side web app (via Ajax), I get an `HTTP 400 Bad Request` error from S3:

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidToken</Code>
    <Message>The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.</Message>
    <!-- account-specific stuff removed -->
</Error>
```

Why is this happening?

Some extra details:

- This is deployed to an EC2 server that gets its IAM role assigned automatically. I've confirmed the authorization from the role is correctly made available to my Python code. All other parts of my code — including `generate_url()` calls that generate `GET` URLs — work fine, using the `ACCESS_KEY_ID` passed automatically to the EC2 instance's environment.
- Python 2.7.9 and Boto 2.38.0.
- The IAM role appears to have all appropriate permissions, as evidenced by the fact that other parts of my code are successfully interacting with S3 (getting items and creating items) using the role. It's only this particular `PUT` that's not working.
- The front-end logic sends a `Content-Type` header, which is why that header is in there. I tried removing the `Content-Type` header from this Boto code and from the front-end logic, but the problem still happens.

Comment: It is boto issue. Boto sdk should be 2.5.1 or mmore

Comment: @IshaaRora: Boto 2.5.1 was released in June 2012 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto/2.5.1). I'm using Boto 2.38.0, released in April 2015 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto/2.38.0).

Comment: What region are you using? Is there are reason that you are using boto instead of boto3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took me over a year to figure it out — but I finally did.

The issue was that my front-end JavaScript was calling `decodeURIComponent()` on the signed URL just before it made the Ajax request.

Before my switch to IAM Roles, this wasn't a problem because the signed URLs didn't have any funny characters in them — so `decodeURIComponent()` had no effect. But IAM Roles use a different signed URL syntax: the query string includes many slashes, which were being over-unescaped by `decodeURIComponent()`.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I'm not able to replicate this problem. I've set up a brand new EC2 instance, assigned it an IAM role which has the AmazonS3FullAccess permission attached

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The earliest Python version I was able to install was 2.7.12 with Boto 2.38.0

```
[root@ip-172-31-13-14 ~]# python -V
Python 2.7.12
[root@ip-172-31-13-14 ~]# pip freeze|grep boto
boto==2.38.0
botocore==1.5.95
```

I then run the code **app.py**

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection


def get_signed_upload_url():
    BUCKET = 'test'
    KEY = 'test-2'
    s3 = S3Connection(is_secure=True)
    return s3.generate_url(300, 'PUT', bucket=BUCKET, key=KEY,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = get_signed_upload_url()
    print "curl -v -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -d @hello2.txt '" + url + "'"
```

Then run the resultant cURL command and the file is uploaded successfully

```
> Host: test.s3.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/plain
> Content-Length: 8585
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: redacted
< x-amz-request-id: redacted
< Date: Tue, 19 Dec 2017 05:45:15 GMT
< x-amz-version-id: redacted
< ETag: "redacted"
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: AmazonS3
```

At this stage I can only guess that perhaps the IAM role you're using doesn't have sufficient privileges to perform the PUT action? Failing that, there could be a difference in the way your client side code is actually performing the PUT request, but this is not very likely.

Other things to check:

- Ensure the clock time on the EC2 instance is accurate
- Ensure the AWS_REGION environment variable is set

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to investigate this! I've confirmed the EC2 instance and S3 bucket are in the same region. I'll try messing with the IAM role.

Comment: I've set the Role to full S3 access, exactly as in your JSON above, and the problem still happens.

Answer (score 0):

It is the permission issue while generating signed URL. Can you please provide the Role which you have attached to Instance.

Try running this command explicitly on EC to see where exactly it is failing.

If it not role issue, then surely there is an issue with boto SDK which you are using. It should be 2.5.1 or later version.

Did you try putting access key and secret key as None?